# To compare UUID, can I use == or have to use UUID.equals(UUID)?

Tags: java

Just start using `java.util.UUID`. My question is if I have two UUID variables, say u1 and u2, and I would like to check if they are equal, can I safely use expression `u1 == u2` or have to write `u1.equals(u2)`? assuming both are not null.

BTW, I am using its `randomUUID` method to create new UUID values, but I think this should not be matter. 
I wonder as UUID is unique, each value could be a singleton, then it is safe to use `u1 == u2`.

```
void method1(UUID u1, UUID u2) {

   // I know it is always safe to use equal method
   if (u1.equals(u2)){ 
     // do something
   }

   // is it safe to use  ==
   if (u1 == u2) {
     // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Your post is confusing. Of course, `==` is enough if you are really talking about **variables**. What is the real scenario?

Comment: the java doc does not answer this question.

Comment: The presence of `==` on `Object`s is tantamount to a bug in Java. Occasions for its use are rare.

Comment: You *could* use `==` for UUIDs, but only if you had some very strong guarantees about how they're used (never created via deserialization; never copied; never provided by any outside code). It's not worth it. Use `.equals`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It depends: which type of equality do you want?

```
UUID a = new UUID(12345678, 87654321);
UUID b = new UUID(12345678, 87654321);
UUID c = new UUID(11111111, 22222222);

System.out.println(a == a); // returns true
System.out.println(a.equals(a)); // returns true

System.out.println(a == b); // returns false
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // returns true

System.out.println(a == c); // returns false
System.out.println(a.equals(c)); // returns false
```

`a == b` is true only if `a` and `b` are the same object. If they are two identical objects, it will still be false.

`a.equals(b)` is true if `a` and `b` are the same UUID value - if their two parts are the same.

It's a rhetorical question, by the way. Almost always you want `.equals`. There isn't much use for `==` with UUIDs.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I should have thought about writing such a piece of code myself to verify. Thanks.

Comment: At beginning, I thought as each UUID value is unique, why not implement each value as a singleton.

Comment: @NewyachtZhang first, `new` *always* creates a new object, so you'd need to use something else like (hypothetically) `UUID.get`. Also, presumably these "singletons" are created on demand (otherwise there would be 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 objects) so they're not actually singletons. Also, it would be a waste of time to track all the UUID objects in existence and search through them every time you use a UUID. Also, the only benefit is to let you use `==`. Is it worth it? (If it was, they'd also do it with String)

Comment: It's a rhetorical question by the way. *Obviously* you want `.equals` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Well...no.

`==` against an object checks for reference equality.  That is, it checks to see if these two objects are literally the same spot in memory.

`.equals()` will check for actual object equivalence.  And, the [Javadoc for `UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#compareTo%28java.util.UUID%29) goes into great detail to explain when two `UUID` instances are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Uncommonly they are no flyweight objects because of bad ood (and wont be for compatibility reasons)! So, its a mind-trap.

Only in flyweight objects who provide a static-factory-method to create instances only you can be quite sure take usage of `==` instead of `.equals(`. Unfortunately because you have a public constructor its no flyweight-pattern.

This means you indeed have to use `.equals(`.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals()` method of `UUID` class in Java is used to check for the equality of one UUID with another. The method returns `true` if both the UUIDs are exactly identical bit by bit.

Syntax:

```java
public boolean equals(Object uuidObj)
```